DS3231 set time compiling to wrong date and time
I am working on a project where I need to set the alarm on a DS3231 to wake an ESP32 at a specified time. In my workflow, I upload three scripts: one to set the time on the DS3231, one to set the alarm, and one that contains the firmware for my device (which will then reset the alarm once it determines that it has fired).
I am running into an occasional, but occasionally persistent, problem where my DS3231 time is consistently sets wrong.
I am using RTClib to manage the DS3231, and a slightly modified version of the "ds3231" sketch that is included in the arduino library. I ported this sketch to PlatformIO in VSCode, which is what I'm using to upload all the scripts for this project.
Here's my main.cpp code:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};


// put function declarations here:

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);

#ifndef ESP8266
  while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
#endif
  Serial.println("Testing the Serial Port");
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    Serial.flush();
    while (1) delay(10);
  }

  if (rtc.lostPower()) {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, let's set the time!");
    // When time needs to be set on a new device, or after a power loss, the
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
   // rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    //Serial.println("Resetting the RTC to:");
    //Serial.println(__DATE__);
    //Serial.println(__TIME__);
    //Serial.println("3:31PM on 23rd September 2024 (hard coded in)");
    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
    // September 23, 2034 at 3:31PM you would call:
    // rtc.adjust(DateTime(2024, 9, 23, 15, 31, 0));
  }

  // When time needs to be re-set on a previously configured device, the
  // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
  // rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
  // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
  // rtc.adjust(DateTime(2014, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0));
   rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
   delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Resetting the RTC to:");
    Serial.println(__DATE__);
    Serial.println(__TIME__);
}

void loop() {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();

    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(" (");
    Serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
    Serial.print(") ");
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.print(" since midnight 1/1/1970 = ");
    Serial.print(now.unixtime());
    Serial.print("s = ");
    Serial.print(now.unixtime() / 86400L);
    Serial.println("d");

    // calculate a date which is 7 days, 12 hours, 30 minutes, 6 seconds into the future
    DateTime future (now + TimeSpan(7,12,30,6));

    Serial.print(" now + 7d + 12h + 30m + 6s: ");
    Serial.print(future.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(future.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(future.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(future.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(future.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(future.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(rtc.getTemperature());
    Serial.println(" C");

    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
}

// put function definitions here:

The way I understand this code is that it should set the DS3231 time to the time at which the script compiles (DATE and TIME). Sometimes this is what happens, but recently it keeps bringing me back to 20th September:

Sometimes this works, and if I set the time manually it works. It has persisted across multiple ESP32 modules. I haven't tried switching out the RTC on this particular project, because it's hard soldered into my board, but I've had this problem on multiple earlier projects and I'm finally curious/annoyed enough to ask the question. Does anyone know what's going on and/or how to fix this? In the past removing the battery from the RTC and re-running the script has worked, but that's not working for me right now.
I am using the sketchy cheap ds3231 modules from Amazon/AliExpress, so maybe there's something wrong with the module? But it seems that it's reading the wrong compilation time for whatever reason.

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

It is always good to say exactly what you expect (i.e. I compiled my code on "1st October"). Not just say "20th September" is wrong. You said "slightly modified version of the "ds3231" sketch". Have you tried the unmodified sketch to see if it has the same problem? "I am using the sketchy cheap ds3231" ... it wouldn't be the 1st time. I would try getting a "real" chip from a known good supplier. Also, the DS3231 spec says you need to send a STOP I2C command after writing new date/time before reading back the date/time. Also, you might try slowing down the I2C clock.

Also, if this is an Arduino project, you'd probably get more foot traffic over in arduino.stackexchange.com.
